# Displaying bounding box array on leaflet map

Tags: javascript, leaflet, geojson, leaflet-draw, angularjs

I have a set of bounding box arrays which I want to display over leaflet map in my application. The arrays look something like this with the bounding box co-ordinates in it:

```
Array[4]
0:
-2.362060546875
1:
51.96245837645124
2:
7.62162297964096
3:
51.96245837645124
```

The number of arrays can increase depending on the searching done by user. I want to have a functionality where it goes through each array and displays the bounding box on map. Any suggestions?

Here is how I am fetching the data and storing bounding box in separate array

```
    function map(obj){

               var o = obj.data.hits.hits;
               var b=[];
                for(var i in o){
                    o[i]._source.id = o[i]._source.compendium_id;
                    try{
                    b.push(o[i]._source.metadata.o2r.spatial.union.geojson.bbox);
                    throw error()
                  }
                  catch (g){
                    console.error("missing spatial");
                    }
                }
                $log.debug('mconfiging result: %o', o,b);
                return obj;
            }
here is my map creation

angular.extend($scope, {
                center: {
                    lat: 51.505,
                    lng: 10.09,
                    zoom: 3
                },
                controls: {
                  scale:true,
                  draw: {}

                },


                layers: {
                    baselayers: {
                        mapbox_light: {
                            name: 'Mapbox Streets',
                            url: 'https://api.mapbox.com/styles/v1/mapbox/streets-v10/tiles/256/{z}/{x}/{y}?access_token=pk.eyJ1IjoicmVoYW5zNTE2IiwiYSI6ImNpeWxjcWNkODAwNGwzM3FxamR6a2gxOXkifQ.PuUfs90MyfmVGYVqx0AoUw',
                            type: 'xyz',
                            layerOptions: {
                                apikey: 'pk.eyJ1IjoicmVoYW5zNTE2IiwiYSI6ImNpeWxjcWNkODAwNGwzM3FxamR6a2gxOXkifQ.PuUfs90MyfmVGYVqx0AoUw',
                                mapid: 'mapbox.streets',
                                format: '@2x.png'
                            },
                            layerParams: {
                                showOnSelector: false
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    overlays: {
                        draw: {
                            name: 'draw',
                            type: 'group',
                            visible: true,
                            layerParams: {
                                showOnSelector: false
                            }
                        }


                    }
                }

           });


           leafletData.getMap().then(function(map) {

               leafletData.getLayers().then(function(baselayers) {
                 var drawnItems = baselayers.overlays.draw;
                  map.on('draw:created', function (e) {

                    var layer = e.layer;


                    drawnItems.addLayer(layer);


                    console.log(JSON.stringify(layer.toGeoJSON()));
                  });
               });
           });
```

Answer (score 4):

I'm not really sure about the array of bounding box coordinates in the example - the second and fourth points are identical, meaning this will never make a box.

In any case, have you looked at [L.Rectangle](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#rectangle)?

```
// starting with the coordinate array you posted, 
// but arbitrarily changed the last point to 52 from 51
var box = [-2.362060546875, 51.96245837645124, 7.62162297964096, 52.96245837645124];

// define rectangle geographical bounds
var bounds = [[box[1], box[0]], [box[3], box[2]]];

// create an orange rectangle
L.rectangle(bounds, {color: "#ff7800", weight: 1}).addTo(map);
map.fitBounds(bounds);
```

This could easily be extended to work with an array of arrays

Comment: thanks for answering. yea i tried this but the problem is that plain leaflet (L.rectangle or L.geojson) don't work with angular leaflet directive which i am using. do you know a workaround for that? plus i am also confused as to how would this be extended when working with multiple arrays as determining coordinates and styling for each box?